# Read both image data and metadata with one invocation of convert

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am working on an image manipulation tool, and I am currently using imagemagick in a subprocess to decompress (and compress) images. This is working well, but it looks like I have to do *two* parallel invocations of `convert` to get all the data I need:

```
convert jpeg:- rgb:-  # To read the image data
convert jpeg:- info:- # To read metadata, such as the dimensions of the image
```

The dimensions of the image are of course essential to make sense of the raw image data obtained with `rgb`.

This seems to be wasteful. Ideally, I'd like to get both kinds of data with one invocation of `convert`, so the source image only has to be processed once. Possible solutions could be:

- Some way of getting `convert` to write `rgb` data to one file descriptor while writing `info` data to another, both based on the same input image. I can't seem to find out how to do this, but `convert` has surprised me with its versatility before. Any idea? (Something like `convert jpeg:- info:fd:2 rgb:-`, but this is interpreted as two inputs, not two outputs)
- Some output format that is as simple to read (from node.js) as `rgb`, but which includes image dimensions. I consider `bmp` too hairy for this task. Is there another format I should consider? The [list of supported formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) is pretty long, so any hint here would be helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using PNM format, it is really simple and documented [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format).

```
convert jpeg:- pnm:-
```

If you use `-compress none`  you will get P1, P2, or P3 and ASCII output of image data, whereas if you do not do that, you will get formats P4, P5 and P6 with ASCII header info and binary (fast!) pixel data.

```
P3
# The P3 means colors are in ASCII, then 3 columns and 2 rows, 
# then 255 for max color, then RGB triplets 
3 2
255
255   0   0     0 255   0     0   0 255
255 255   0   255 255 255     0   0   0
```

Examples:

```
# convert rose: -compress none image.pbm
# P1
# 70 46
# 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
# 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
# 
# convert rose: -compress none image.pgm
# P2
# 70 46
# 255
# 47 48 51 52 52 51 49 50 49 49 48 46 45 46 46 45 46 49 52 54 58 64 67 66 67 68 
# 77 84 89 96 101 103 101 99 96 88 86 86 84 81 79 78 78 78 80 81 89 92 86 62 54 
# 
# convert rose: -compress none image.ppm
# P3
# 70 46
# 255
# 48 47 45 50 48 46 54 50 47 56 51 46 58 51 45 57 50 45 56 48 45 57 49 46 
# 56 48 45 56 48 45 55 47 44 53 45 42 52 44 41 53 45 42 53 45 42 49 45 39 
# 
# convert rose: image.pbm
# P4
# 70 46
# 
# convert rose: image.pgm
# P5
# 70 46
# 255
# 
# convert rose: image.ppm
# P6
# 70 46
# 255
```

Comment: Thank you, that *does* look simple to read. I'm going to use the image data in binary, so this would add a pretty massive overhead for the large images I'm using, unfortunately.

Comment: I was in the middle of updating in anticipation of your request! Please look again.

Comment: Well, that looks perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [fd:](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#fd) file handler to redirect the output to different file handles.

```
convert jpeg:- -write info:fd:2 rgb:fd:1
```

The `info:` will be in stderr, and `rgb:` will be in stdout. Use basic [I/O redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) to handle as needed.

Comment: This is also perfect! Thanks guys :)